# Can anyone please describe "warehouse-13" tag?

Tags: support, tags

I viewed [warehouse-13](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warehouse-13) tag page which has bunch of questions, but no description.

Can someone please update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag appears to have an extensive description;

[image]

Comment: Oh, looks like tag description isn't displayed on mobile site..